# Loop object private array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am sure my loop code is wrong, but for the life of me, I cannot see what it is.

I have to create a `Student(String name, double gpa)` object.

I have a class Classroom that initializes a private array `students[]`. I ask the user how many students to create. Using a loop, I ask for the name and gpa of each student and I add it in the array with the `add(Student aStudent)` method. My method is supposed to check if the cell is null. If it is, add the object. If not, go to next cell. I cannot create multiple `Student` objects.

I also have a get method to return the reference of a specific array cell.

Here is the class `Classroom`, `add` and `get` method. The variables are set by the assignment.

```
public class Classroom {

    private boolean hasSpace = false;
    int maxClassroomSize;
    private Student students[];

    public Classroom (int size){
        maxClassroomSize = size;
        students = new Student[maxClassroomSize];


    }



    public boolean add (Student aStudent) {
        for(int i = 0; i <=(students.length-1); i++)
        {
            if (students[i] == null) {
                students[i] = aStudent;
                hasSpace = true;
            } else hasSpace = false;
        } return hasSpace;          
    }


    public Student getStudent(int position){
            return students[position];

    }

}
```

Here is my main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {



public static void main(String[] args) {


    int classSize;
    int numberStudentsInput;
    double gpa = 0;
    String studentName = null;
    Student student1 = new Student();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How big is this class?");
    classSize = sc.nextInt();

    Classroom classroom = new Classroom(classSize);

    do{
    System.out.println("How many students are enrolled in this class?");
    numberStudentsInput = sc.nextInt();

        if (numberStudentsInput>classSize)
            System.out.println("Too many students for the class size. Please try again. ");

    } while (numberStudentsInput >classSize);



    for (int i=0; i<=(numberStudentsInput-1);i++) {


        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the student's name: ");
        studentName = sc2.nextLine();
        student1.setName(studentName);

        System.out.println("What is the student's GPA");
        gpa = sc2.nextDouble();
        student1.setGPA(gpa);
        classroom.add(student1);    
    }

    System.out.println(student1.getName(classroom.getStudent(0)));
    System.out.println(student1.getName(classroom.getStudent(1)));


}

}
```

I am outputting the name of array cell 0 and 1 to see the result but it seems to only keep the latest input. So if I enter "John" and "Paul" as the names, my output would be "Paul" for both cells.

I think my add method is correct, but I am most surely wrong...  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same Student object to all cells.  So when you change that object, you are changing it both in the old cells that already have it, and in the new cell to which you are adding it.  You say you "cannot create multiple Student objects."  I don't understand why not, but that is at the heart of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new Student object inside the for loop

```
Student student1;

for(...) {
 student = new Student(); 
 ..
 classroom.add(student);
}
```